# Pagination implementations is causing data to constantly change

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a React Native app that uses a firestore database. The database contains a collection 'gigs' that contain documents pertaining to live music gigs. 
I've built a custom hook `useGigs.tsx` to fetch gig data, which is consumed in `List.tsx` to render a list of gigs. 

**Problem** 
Since I introduced pagination logic to my hook, the list has displayed strange behaviour - it alternates between showing no gigs, then a small list of gigs, then an entirely new list of gigs - then it crashes with the error

> ERROR  FirebaseError: Function startAfter() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Could I please get some help getting my hook to paginate successfully? I'm not sure what's causing this error.
If it's any help, the `dateAndTime` property is a firebase timestamp.

Code follows:

**useGigs.tsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {  collection, onSnapshot, query, where, orderBy,startAt, startAfter, limit } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from '../firebase'
import { GigObject } from '../routes/homeStack'

export interface Time {
  nanoseconds:number
  seconds:number;
}

export const useGigs = (userLocation?:string) => {
  const [gigs, setGigs] = useState<GigObject[]>([])
  const [lastDocument, setLastDocument] = useState(null); 

  useEffect(() => {
    let gigQuery;

    if (userLocation && userLocation.trim() !== "") {
      // Filter by city if userLocation is defined and not empty
      gigQuery = query(
        collection(db, 'gigs'), 
        where('city', '==', userLocation),
        orderBy('dateAndTime'),
        startAfter(lastDocument), 
        limit(10));
    } else {
      // Otherwise, get all gigs
      gigQuery = collection(db, 'gigs');
    }

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(gigQuery, (querySnapshot) => {
      const queriedGigs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          tickets: doc.data().tickets || "",
          venue: doc.data().venue || "Unknown Venue",
          dateAndTime: doc.data().dateAndTime || { seconds: 0, nanoseconds: 0 },
          isFree: doc.data().isFree || false,
          image: doc.data().image || "",
          genre: doc.data().genre || "",
          gigName: doc.data().gigName || "",
          blurb: doc.data().blurb || "",
          location: doc.data().location || { longitude: 0, latitude: 0 },
          address: doc.data().address || "",
          gigName_subHeader: doc.data().gigName_subHeader || "",
          links: doc.data().links || [],
          ticketPrice: doc.data().ticketPrice || "",
          likes: doc.data().likes || 0,
          likedGigs: doc.data().likedGigs || [],
          savedGigs: doc.data().savedGigs || [],
          city: doc.data().city || "Unknown City",
      }))
      setGigs(queriedGigs)
      const lastDoc = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
      setLastDocument(lastDoc);
    })

    // Cleanup the subscription when the component unmounts
    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [userLocation, lastDocument])

  return gigs
}
```

**List.tsx (styles ommitted)**

```
import { FC,useContext,useState,useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity,Platform } from "react-native";
import { useGigs } from "../hooks/useGigs";
import GigsByDay from "./GigsByDay";
import GigsByWeek from "./GigsByWeek";
import { listProps } from "../routes/homeStack";
import { getGigsToday, getGigsThisWeek } from "../util/helperFunctions";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import { AuthContext } from "../AuthContext";
import { useGetUser } from "../hooks/useGetUser";
import { useLocation } from "../LocationContext";

type ListScreenNavigationProp = listProps["navigation"];

interface Props {
  navigation: ListScreenNavigationProp;
}

const ListByDay: FC<Props> = ({ navigation }): JSX.Element => {
  const [showWeek, setShowByWeek] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [ gigs, setGigs ] = useState([])
  const currentDateMs: number = Date.now();
  const { selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation } = useLocation();
  const {user} = useContext(AuthContext) || {}
  const userDetails = useGetUser(user?.uid);

  const locationToUse = user && userDetails?.userLocation ? userDetails.userLocation : selectedLocation;

  const gigsDataFromHook = useGigs(locationToUse);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (gigsDataFromHook) {
      setGigs([...gigsDataFromHook]);
    }
  }, [gigsDataFromHook]);


  const gigsToday = getGigsToday(gigs, currentDateMs);
  const gigsThisWeek = getGigsThisWeek(gigs, currentDateMs);

  const formattedDay = format(new Date(currentDateMs),'EEEE')
  const formattedWeek = format(new Date(currentDateMs),'LLLL do Y')


  const gigsToRender = showWeek ? (
    Object.keys(gigsThisWeek).length === 0 ? (
      <Text style = {{fontFamily: 'LatoRegular', marginLeft:'7%'}}>No gigs this week</Text>
    ) : (
      <GigsByWeek gigsThisWeek_grouped={gigsThisWeek} navigation={navigation} />
    )

  ) : (
     gigsToday?.length === 0 ? (
      <Text style = {{fontFamily: 'LatoRegular', marginLeft:'7%'}}>No gigs today</Text>
     ) : (
      <GigsByDay navigation={navigation} gigsFromSelectedDate={gigsToday} />
     )
  );

  const showDate = !showWeek ? (
    <View testID="gigMapHeader" style={styles.headerText}>
      <Text style={styles.headerText_main}>{formattedDay}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.headerText_sub}>{formattedWeek}</Text>
    </View>
  ) : (
      null
  );


  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => setShowByWeek(false)}
          style={!showWeek ? styles.touchable : styles.selected}
        >
          <Text style = {!showWeek ? styles.buttonText : styles.buttonTextSelected}>Gigs Today</Text>  
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => setShowByWeek(true)}
          style={showWeek ? styles.touchable : styles.selected}
        >
        <Text style = {showWeek ? styles.buttonText : styles.buttonTextSelected}>Gigs this Week</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      {showDate}

      <View style = {styles.listContainer}>
        {gigsToRender}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: If the error comes from your `gigQuery`, I recommend `console.log`ing `lastDocument` and its data right before you use them in there.

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect listens to changes of **lastDocument** and you update this value within your useEffect hooks. Which means that the useEffect triggers an update that triggers it to rerender infinitely until you've reached the end of the collection which yields an undefined which raises an error.

```js
ERROR FirebaseError: Function startAfter() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined
```

So before looping over your **querySnapshot.docs**, make sure it exists. Protect the callback of your **onSnapshot** with a try/catch:

```js
querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
   try {
   ...
   } catch (err) {
      //display an error in screens listening to the hooks
   }
 })
```

Then remove the **lastDocument** from the dependency array of the useEffect. Your linter should throw a warning but it's completely fine.